# GnuTLS doesn't correctly verify certs for googleapis.com

Tags: ssl, gnutls

I originally asked a [related question on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/171983/27877). Here's the MCVE.

Short version: when I use GnuTLS to verify an HTTPS connection to googleapis.com, it fails verification. For other sites (e.g. github.com), it succeeds.

I'm loading the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file explicitly (in the real program, we cache it, rather than hit the filesystem every time).

The CA store was [updated recently](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates/20170717~14.04.1) by Ubuntu. Prior to that update, the following code works. Since the update, it fails.

*Ubuntu 14.04, compile with `g++ -o gnutls-client gnutls-client.cpp -lgnutls`*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <gnutls/x509.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define CURL_CA_BUNDLE "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"   // FAILS
//#define CURL_CA_BUNDLE "old-ca-certificates.crt"      // WORKS

#define CHECK(x) assert((x) >= 0);

// Fails with sheets.googleapis.com
// Succeeds with (e.g.) github.com

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *server_name = argv[1];

    gnutls_global_init();
    printf("gnutls-client (GnuTLS/%s)\n", gnutls_check_version(NULL));

    gnutls_certificate_credentials_t creds = NULL;
    CHECK(gnutls_certificate_allocate_credentials(&creds));
    gnutls_certificate_set_verify_flags(creds,
                    GNUTLS_VERIFY_ALLOW_X509_V1_CA_CRT);
    int certificateCount = gnutls_certificate_set_x509_trust_file(creds,
                    CURL_CA_BUNDLE, GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM);
    if (certificateCount >= 0) {
        printf("%d certificate(s) processed\n", certificateCount);
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to set trust file: %d\n", certificateCount);
        exit(1);
    }

    gnutls_session_t session = NULL;
    CHECK(gnutls_init(&session, GNUTLS_CLIENT));

    CHECK(gnutls_server_name_set(session, GNUTLS_NAME_DNS,
        server_name, strlen(server_name)));
    CHECK(gnutls_set_default_priority(session));
    CHECK(gnutls_credentials_set(session, GNUTLS_CRD_CERTIFICATE, creds));

    struct addrinfo hint, *addr;
    memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
    hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo(server_name, "https", &hint, &addr);

    int sockfd = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
    CHECK(connect(sockfd, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen));

    gnutls_transport_set_int(session, sockfd);

    int ret;
    do {
        ret = gnutls_handshake(session);
    } while (ret < 0 && gnutls_error_is_fatal(ret) == 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ret: %d\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connected: %s\n", gnutls_session_get_desc(session));

    unsigned int peercerts_size;
    const gnutls_datum_t *peercerts = gnutls_certificate_get_peers(session,
        &peercerts_size);

    printf("Server presented %d certs\n", peercerts_size);

    unsigned int verify_status;
    CHECK(gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2(session, &verify_status));
    printf("%d 0x%x\n", ret, verify_status);
    assert(verify_status == 0x0);

    return 0;
}
```

With the current CA bundle...

```
$ ./gnutls-client github.com
gnutls-client (GnuTLS/3.2.11)
148 certificate(s) processed
Connected: (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-RSA-SECP256R1)-(AES-128-GCM)
Server presented 2 certs
0 0x0

$ ./gnutls-client googleapis.com
gnutls-client (GnuTLS/3.2.11)
148 certificate(s) processed
Connected: (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-ECDSA-SECP256R1)-(AES-128-GCM)
Server presented 3 certs
0 0x42
gnutls-client: gnutls-client.cpp:82: int main(int, char**): Assertion `verify_status == 0x0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

With the previous CA bundle...

```
$ ./gnutls-client github.com
gnutls-client (GnuTLS/3.2.11)
173 certificate(s) processed
Connected: (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-RSA-SECP256R1)-(AES-128-GCM)
Server presented 2 certs
0 0x0

$ ./gnutls-client googleapis.com
gnutls-client (GnuTLS/3.2.11)
173 certificate(s) processed
Connected: (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-ECDSA-SECP256R1)-(AES-128-GCM)
Server presented 3 certs
0 0x0
```

`gnutls-cli`, on the same machine, works fine:

```
$ gnutls-cli googleapis.com --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt 
Processed 148 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'googleapis.com'...
Connecting to '108.177.119.105:443'...
- Certificate type: X.509
 - Got a certificate list of 3 certificates.
 - Certificate[0] info:
  - subject `C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=*.googleapis.com', issuer `C=US,O=Google Inc,CN=Google Internet Authority G2', RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2017-10-17 10:22:56 UTC', expires `2017-12-29 00:00:00 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `34e45ef97aadd3e73978790c2f16ce275a28cd1c'
 - Certificate[1] info:
  - subject `C=US,O=Google Inc,CN=Google Internet Authority G2', issuer `C=US,O=GeoTrust Inc.,CN=GeoTrust Global CA', RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2017-05-22 11:32:37 UTC', expires `2018-12-31 23:59:59 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `a6120fc0b4664fad0b3b6ffd5f7a33e561ddb87d'
 - Certificate[2] info:
  - subject `C=US,O=GeoTrust Inc.,CN=GeoTrust Global CA', issuer `C=US,O=Equifax,OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority', RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA1, activated `2002-05-21 04:00:00 UTC', expires `2018-08-21 04:00:00 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `7359755c6df9a0abc3060bce369564c8ec4542a3'
- The hostname in the certificate matches 'googleapis.com'.
- Peer's certificate is trusted
- Version: TLS1.2
- Key Exchange: RSA
- Cipher: AES-128-CBC
- MAC: SHA1
- Compression: NULL
- Handshake was completed

- Simple Client Mode:

^C
```

(Note the "Peer's certificate is trusted")

The "Equifax" certificate was removed in the update, but according to the security.stackexchange.com question, GnuTLS should see the intermediate "GeoTrust" certificate and treat that as a valid root.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you reproduce the problems with gnutls-cli?

Comment: No. I forgot to include that. Updated question.

Comment: *Ubuntu 14.04* - code does not compile on this platform since the gnutls is there 2.12.23. Thus it looks like you are using something customized. Code does compile on 16.04 though with version 3.4.10 and shows no problems.

Comment: "customized" is a bit strong for `apt-get install libgnutls28-dev`, which is the only relevant difference between my machine and a vanilla 14.04 box...

Comment: But that's a useful pointer, thanks.

Comment: But what version is the gnutls-cli on your machine? When installing `libgnutls28-dev` I can compile your code and reproduce the problem. But `gnutls-cli -v` still reports version 2.12.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... apt-get install libgnutls28-dev, which is the only relevant difference between my machine and a vanilla 14.04 box

There is a known problem with this version in exactly the situation you describe. For more details and a patch see [gnutls28 in trusty no longer validates many valid certificate chains, such as google.com](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls28/+bug/1722411).

> $ gnutls-cli googleapis.com --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
>   ...
>   - Peer's certificate is trusted

gnutls-cli is still using the original gnutls version 2.12.23 which comes by default with Ubuntu 14.04 (see output of `gnutls-cli -v`). This version does not seem to be affected by the problem.

Comment: That patch appears to work: I've got a patched deb file which appears to fix the problem.